# Interact with swift object with memory location in the debugger

Tags: swift, lldb

Suppose I know, based on earlier console output, that at some memory location is an object of interest:

```
<MySpecialObject:0x7a5125a0 This is a description of my special object>
```

In the ObjC debugger I could do something like `po [0x7a5125a0 myMethod:arg1 arg2:arg2]` to interact with this object in the debugger.

I could also do this:

```
(lldb) expr MySpecialObject *$foo = 0x7a5125a0
(lldb) po [foo myMethod:arg1 arg2:arg2]
```

What is the way to accomplish this effect (interact with object in lldb given its memory address) when debugging a Swift program?

Comment: Debugging in swift is broken at this point.

Answer (score 23):

One thing you could try is the following:

```
(lldb) expr -l objc++ -O -- [(id)0xmyFancyAddressGoesHere selector]
```

Your mileage may vary but essentially this is the glorified version of what you would do in ObjC (except that now you're in Swift-land so you have to force the expression evaluator in ObjC mode (-l objc++), and you can't rely on the "po" alias, so you need to explicitly ask for "object description behavior" (-O)

Of course, if you find yourself doing this often, you can make your own alias for "expr -l objc++ -O --"

Answer (score 10):

In Swift you use the `unsafeBitcast` function to cast a memory address to a variable in lldb.

```
expr $mv = unsafeBitCast(0x7a66cdb0, MapView.self)
```

This would cast the memory address to a `MapVie` object. When you're casting your own objects, you may find that you have to `import` your project's module into lldb.

Update for Swift 4:
it appears that the syntax changes slightly in Xcode 10.1 so the `unsafeBitCast` part now needs to name the second parameter and we add a `let` (or maybe `var` depending). So, the example above now becomes

```
expr let $mv = unsafeBitCast(0x7a66cdb0, to: MapView.self)
```

Comment: This seems to be the Swift equivalent of what I've been doing for decades— `(MapView *)0x7a66cdb0`.  I like.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the Swift equivalent. There is an article about using it by Mike Ash [at his website] (https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-12-11-swift-weak-references.html) and the people over at realm.io [wrote about it recently as well](https://realm.io/news/swift-summit-boris-bugling-runtime-funtime/)

Comment: "<EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier '$mv'" Not sure if I'm doing it right...

Comment: @surfrider I just did some fiddling around in the console in Xcode 10.1 and I got the same error. It appears that we now have to give our variable a type. So `expr int $mv = 2` is fine but `expr $mv = 2` throws the error you're seeing. I'll dig around and see if I can update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such way. Debugging Swift is pretty much a non-starter. Evaluation of expressions and inspection of variables while paused is totally broken. You're better off using `println` or `NSLog` for now.

**EDIT** That was a year ago. LLDB is greatly improved for use with Swift now!

Comment: greatly improved.. so is there a way to reference a memory address now? :/

Answer (score 3):

Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)
I am debugging the view hierarchy. I have my own subclass of UIImage view. Here it is how it works for me :

```
(lldb) po 0x7fc6ecb55e30

<Lesson_1_Quartz_Composer.Layer: 0x7fc6ecb55e30; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 320 49.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fc6ecb6df20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc6ecb55f30>>

(lldb) po [0x7fc6ecb55e30 isUserInteractionEnabled]
0x0000000182002001

(lldb) po (bool)[0x7fc6ecb55e30 isUserInteractionEnabled]
true

(lldb)  expr -l objc++ -O -- [(id)0x7fc6ecb55e30 isUserInteractionEnabled]
0x0000000182002001
```

Obviously it is a UIView subclass, so it objective-c, but it mixes with Swift.